# Align horizontally Views programmatically in a Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, expandablelistview

I want to Align programmatically TextViews in a RelativeLayout. Like this:

```
Title of row
Other views -- TextView 1 TextView2 TextView3 etc.. -- other views
```

So i have a foreach that is the loop for adding programmatically my textViews. 
This is my foreach:

```
for(DocumentField d: listOfFields){
                            if(d.isHighlighted()){
                                TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                txt.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shp_round_corners));
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                                params.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                                txt.setLayoutParams(params);
                                txt.setTag("field");
                                GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)txt.getBackground();
                                if(usedcolorMap.get(code) != null)
                                    drawable.setColor(usedcolorMap.get(code));
                                if(d.isNumeric())
                                    txt.setText(d.convertedNumber());
                                else if(d.isText())
                                    txt.setText(d.getTextValue());
                                else if(d.isDate())
                                    txt.setText(d.convertedDate());
                                String text = txt.getText().toString();
                                if(metrics.densityDpi <= DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM){
                                    if(text.length() > 8)
                                        text = text.substring(0, 8).trim() + "...";
                                }else if(text.length() > 15){
                                    text = text.substring(0, 15).trim() + "...";
                                }
                                txt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                txt.setTextSize(12);
                                txt.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                txt.setText(text);
                                ll.addView(txt);
                            }
                        }
```

and xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:id="@+id/doc_fields"
    android:tag="ll"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doc_tag"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

The result of this code is that the textViews are overlapped. I want to use Relative layout only for better performances

I tryed with this rule:

```
if(idOltText != 0)
                                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, idOltText);
```

but is still not working..

Comment: Why dont you use a LinearLayout with a Horizontal orientation?

Comment: with Linear Layout work very well.. but this is a layout of an item of a List.. so the performance are bad with a lot of items

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, If it is performance you are worried about why are you not using a ListView? A ListView is built to offer performance for large lists.

Comment: I m using a listview with a Simple Cursor Adapter.. but for 200 items a Linear Layout for each row is very bad for performance.. I tried it..

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, I have listviews with over 3000 items in with more complex layouts and have great performance. Where is the code above? We would need to see more of the Adapter. - The performance is likely this foreach loop you are running for each list item. You should really be doing this kind of thing inside of the adapter (getView())

Comment: I changed from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and performances are growed up..  the adapter is a classical implementation of a ViewBinder newView with a Switch(view.getID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved.. this is the update of my loop:

```
int idOltText = 0;
                        for(DocumentField d: listOfFields){
                            if(d.isHighlighted()){
                                TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                txt.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shp_round_corners));
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                                params.setMargins(3, 0, 0, 0);
                                if(idOltText != 0){
                                    System.out.println(idOltText);
                                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, idOltText);
                                }
                                txt.setLayoutParams(params);
                                txt.setTag("field");
                                GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)txt.getBackground();
                                if(usedcolorMap.get(code) != null)
                                    drawable.setColor(usedcolorMap.get(code));
                                if(d.isNumeric())
                                    txt.setText(d.convertedNumber());
                                else if(d.isText())
                                    txt.setText(d.getTextValue());
                                else if(d.isDate())
                                    txt.setText(d.convertedDate());
                                String text = txt.getText().toString();
                                if(metrics.densityDpi <= DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM){
                                    if(text.length() > 8)
                                        text = text.substring(0, 8).trim() + "...";
                                }else if(text.length() > 15){
                                    text = text.substring(0, 15).trim() + "...";
                                }
                                txt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                txt.setTextSize(12);
                                txt.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                txt.setText(text);
                                idOltText++;
                                txt.setId(idOltText);
                                ll.addView(txt);

                            }
                        }
```